# Block Not Seen by Controller Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, adminhtml

I have a module that primarily works with the admin-side of Magento 2.

At the minute, I'm just trying to parse a CSV file and log the contents, here's a **skimmed** version of my Block class:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Import.php

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml;

    class Import extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
    {    
        public function parseFile($file)
        {
            foreach (array_map('str_getcsv', file($file)) as $num => $row)
            {
                $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/bob.log');
                $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
                $logger->addWriter($writer);
                $logger->info(print_r($row, 1). PHP_EOL);
            }
        }
    }
```

Which I attempt to call in my (**skimmed**) Controller class:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Import/Submit.php

```
class Submit extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_resultLayoutFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_resultLayoutFactory = $resultLayoutFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $files = (array) $this->getRequest()->getFiles();

        if (!empty($files)) {
            $importFile = $files['import_file'];

            if (!$importFile['error']) {
                $resultLayout = $this->_resultLayoutFactory->create();

                $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/another.log');
                $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
                $logger->addWriter($writer);
                $logger->info($resultLayout->getLayout()->getBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Import'));

            }
        }

        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Going to another.log show's:

> 2020-02-28T14:18:16+00:00 INFO (6):

I've ran:

```
$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade
$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile
$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
$ php bin/magento cache:flush
```

But to no avail. I turned on the **With Block Hints** option in debugging and it matches, so I'm not quite sure why my Controller can't see it.

How do I use my Block class in my Controller class (adminhtml side)?

Comment: Hello you must use createBlock not getBlock and if you want show something in log add ->toHtml()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Call block, PLease update your `Submit.php` file as below:

Replace this code:

```
$logger->info($resultLayout->getLayout()->getBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Import'));
```

With this:

```
$logger->info($resultLayout->getLayout()->create()->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Import'));
```

Hope this help!